# Can not select binary field whit php

Tags: php, mysql, binary, bittorrent

My problem: I can not select a field "binary" with mysql

[image: structure db]

This is query (note the "not equal"):

```
SELECT *
FROM `pt_peers`
WHERE `info_hash` != '7f398565868f7f08f71d236b88e4e433d2311de8'
```

And this is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pt_peers` (
  `info_hash` binary(20) NOT NULL,
  `peer_id` binary(20) NOT NULL,
  `compact` binary(6) NOT NULL,
  `ip` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `port` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `state` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `updated` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`info_hash`,`peer_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

When I select the hash directly, the answer is null. :/

The script is: [PeerTracker](http://code.google.com/p/peertracker/)

Comment: why `NOT IN`? I just want to select rows with hash, but when I select, no results appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be passing a 40 byte string of ASCII representations of hex digits, where the table is defined as holding 20 bytes of binary.

Try this, using a hex literal notation for a binary string:

```
SELECT *
FROM `pt_peers`
WHERE `info_hash` = x'7f398565868f7f08f71d236b88e4e433d2311de8'
```

See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/hexadecimal-literals.html) for more information.

Comment: you are absolutely right! this is exactly the solution, thank you for your help DaveRandom =)

Comment: the operation is done very well, but when I use another hash (nonexistent in db) I have a sql error (and a possible sql injection) :/

Comment: @atmon3r Are you using prepared statements? There shouldn't really be any reason that you would get an error when the hash does not exist, but the hex literal string notation does require an even number of digits in the string. Which DB driver are you using? Can you show some of your query PHP code?

Comment: My db is `Mysql 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1`, and here is [function used](http://pastebin.com/UCwvBb6S). The `WHERE` condition is normally called by a torrent client and not by the browser.

Comment: grieve, I forgot to post the error: `d14:failure reason189:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'x'7f398565868f7f08f71d236b88e4e433d2311se8'' at line 1e`

Comment: @atmon3r Which database driver is running behind `$api`? PDO, MySQLi or ext/mysql?

Comment: Also `FROM \`{$_SERVER['tracker']['db_prefix']}peers\`` - I *really* advise against storing custom data in the system superglobals like this, if you must do something like that I suggest you use `$_SESSION`, but really you should have a config object that can be injected into the class if necessary.

Comment: The script verifies between mysql and mysqli. [All php file](http://pastebin.com/KdzpsNJV)

Comment: @atmon3r The problem you are having, I suspect, is that the info hash has a non-hex character in it. If you look you will see the third character from the end is an `s` - is that a typo for an `a`? Here is what I suggest: http://pastebin.com/yksCzJu0

Comment: Oooh! you have the eye! actually, I created an error to test the reaction of the code (which gave me an error). I looked at your code, if I understand correctly, the hash uses only numbers and character from `a` to `f` with 40 characters. Your code works great! thank you very much for your help, you taught me the good things =)